# .sh to loop through folders recursive-

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

My file path is `/server/2TB_HDD/TV Shows/` (inside this I have about 100 shows, each with seasons in them)

The problem I seem to be having is the file path. "TV Shows" part.

Similar problem if I run it as a .sh

(I'm kinda new to this)

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks

code:

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in /server/'2TB_HDD'/TV\ Shows/*;
  do
     [ -d $f ] && cd "$f" && echo Entering into $f and installing packages
  done;
```

`bash test.sh`:

```
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: /server/2TB_HDD/TV: binary operator expected
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
test.sh: line 4: [: too many arguments
```

Answer (score 3):

Quote `$f` in  the square brackets. Get used to the habit of quoting the variables.

On a side note , one could use alternative approach with `find` , null separator, and `while ... read VAR ; do ...done` structure. Here's for example , me entering each directory and doing `pwd` in each.

```
find /home/xieerqi -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -d $'\0' DIR ; do
    cd "$DIR"
    pwd
    cd ..
done
```

In your case you could do something like ,

```
find "/server/2TB_HDD/TV Shows/" -maxdepth 1 -type d -print0 | while IFS= read -d $'\0' DIR ; do
cd "$DIR" && printf "\nEntering into %s and installing packages\n " "$DIR"
done
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick response.
To make this more complex and create a functional script.

Comment: I am trying to create a script to encode videos. My file structure is as follows.
/server/2TB_HDD/TV Shows/*Many TV Shows*/*Season 1 to 10*/video files.avi/.mkv or .mp4 I want to create a script to run that enters the directory, looks for an .avi or .mkv, checks if there is a .mp4 with the same name already there (processing already done of that file is the past and the script is being rerun) ffmpeg -i INPUT.avi||.mkv -c:v libx264 -b:v 4000K -preset veryslow -c:a copy OUTPUT.mp4 What are your idea on this. Thanks again.